# Mysql Query: Identify available vehicle from specific dates

Tags: mysql, database, date, between

I have a table named **trips** where you save the trip with specified `departure_date` and `return_date`. The vehicles are saved in the **vehicles** table. I need to query all vehicles that are available for a specific dates so that if the vehicle is choosen for a specific trip it *cannot* be used again for another trip until it returns.
 My table structure is like this

Table: **trips**

```
id
vehicle_id
departure_date
return_date
```

Table: **vehicles**

```
id  
plate_no
```

I tried to query using the following command but it does not seem to work:

```
select v.id from vehicles as v
where v.id not in
    (select vehicle_id from trips
     where (departure_date between '2012-10-31 10:41:30' AND '2012-11-06 10:41:38'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
select 
v.id 
from 
vehicles as v 
left join trips t on (v.id=t.vehicle_id)
where 
t.departure_date between '2012-10-31 10:41:30' AND '2012-11-06 10:41:38' 
and t.id is null
```